# Getting following error "collect2: ld returned 1 exit status"

Tags: c, compiler-construction, libm

I have created a C source file using the modules from other source files. Suppose the created source file is abc.c .Mine C file compiles fine using the following command.

```
gcc -c  abc.c
```

I have compiled each and every source file that are linked to the abc.c .While creating the executable file using the following command:

```
 gcc abc.o b.o c.o ....strings.o -o abc
```

It shows the following error, although i have used strings.o for creating executable file:

```
strings.o: In function `string_IntToString':
strings.c:(.text+0x5d3): undefined reference to `log10'
strings.c:(.text+0x606): undefined reference to `log10'
collect2: ld returned 1 exit status
```

Could you suggest me what can be the wrong here?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You forgot to link against libm.

```
gcc ... -lm ...
```